# update text on uitableview header

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I am using the code below to set the uitableview viewForHeaderInSection and then I am trying to update just one textfield in the section header but my reference is nil.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "ReusableHeader")

        header.timeField.text = String(describing: secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: counter))
        return header
    }
```

My reference code where header comes back as nil:

```
let header = self.tableView.headerView(forSection: 0)
        header?.setNeedsLayout()
```

Comment: Why are you attempting to dequeue a cell for a section header? Cells are for rows, not header views.

Comment: I am using a custom cell for my headerview. Is there another way I should be doing it?

Comment: Look at the documentation for `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`.

Comment: I have read it before, what am I missing?

Comment: After reading the documentation you then need to actually use `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` and `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView` instead of using cells for your section header.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165210/on-swipe-to-delete-the-header-and-footer-section-of-the-tableview-swipe-too

Answer (score 0):

Ok , i'am researching about this thing. func **self.tableView.headerView(forSection: )** return only **UITableViewHeaderFooterView** object. If you want use this func , you need use **tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "ReusableHeader")**

```
 public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?{
    let view = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "ReusableHeader")
    return view
}
```